# Webstorm: Cannot Resolve Directory Part 2

Tags: html, image, macos, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm having problems rendering pictures from my internal directories for a Meteor project using the PHPStrom IDE. It keeps giving me the "cannot resolve directory" error as seen here:

[Webstorm: "Cannot Resolve Directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987225/webstorm-cannot-resolve-directory)

The answer therein should help me however it does not reference where to find settings or which settings he's refering to (Mac, Webstorm, Something else?). I have a Mac (I'm new to it and bought an old 2009 off Craigslist recently just so I could use Meteor; I'm learning Mac as I go and it is a strange strange world for a PC user).

Answer (score 1):

I control & clicked on the top folder in PHPStorm. I then went to "Mark Directory As" and selected Mark as Resource Root which fixed the problem for all sub folders.