# Webstorm code inspection can't resolve served file

Tags: html, css, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-inspection

I created a blank project in Webstorm (2018.3) and created the following file structure:

```
.
+--css
|  +--style.css
+--view
   +--index.html
```

I then added this code to the head of `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/css/style.css">
```

Now code inspection feels that this is correct, and indeed that is the path from the project root. However Webstorm will not serve `style.css` from this path, presenting MIME validation errors if I attempt to use it.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:63342/src/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I did some digging into the built-in server for WebStorm which revealed that it includes the project name as part of the root path. I adjusted the path to `style.css` and sure enough, this worked `/JS-Tip/css/style.css`. However this causes the code inspector to complain that it can't resolve the path.

Looking into this problem led me to this question [Webstorm: "Cannot Resolve Directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987225/webstorm-cannot-resolve-directory). So I added `src/` as a resource root, but I was still unable to use it in the path. So I tried setting the project root `Js-Tip/` as a resource root but it did not resolve the inspection warning. I even tried adding both `JS-Tip/` and `src/` as resource roots and it changed nothing, not even when using `JS-Tip/src/css/style.css` as the path.

So my question is, how do I resolve this warning? Or, barring that, how do I get the server to accept `src/` as an acceptable root for the file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a leading slash in your URL (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/css/style.css">`) -
note the leading `/` before `src`. Such slashes tell the browser to resolve URLs from the web server root. But the built-in web server serves files from `http://localhost:63342/<project name>`, so no resources can be loaded from `http://localhost:63342` - thus 404 errors are thrown.

To work out the issue, change URLs to the ones relative to current `.html` file - like `href="../css/style.css"`

Comment: That's it precisely! Thank you, can't believe I overlooked that. Guess that's what happens when you spend all your time in a CMS.